# How to insert date to database in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to insert data into my database, but when I check the database only the date can't be input while the others works just fine.

Here is my controller:

```
   $data = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'order_date' => $request->order_date,
        'order_number' => $request->order_number,
        'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
        'billing_subtotal' => $request->billing_subtotal,
        'billing_tax' => $request->billing_tax,
        'billing_total' => $request->billing_total,
    ]);
```

And my view :

```
 <input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" />
 <input id="order_date" name="order_date" type="hidden" value="{{ date('d M Y', strtotime(today())) }}" />
 <input id="order_number" name="order_number" type="hidden" value="M68{{ date('Ymd', strtotime(today())) }}{{ rand(1000,9999)}}" />
```

Here is what the `orders` table in my database looks like :
[image: orders]

As you can see only the date field is empty. I tried dd($request) and the the date input is not null but won't be inserted to the `orders` table. Here is the dd Request:

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: please read the doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting you need to cast as date in model then you can do that

Comment: Is `order_date` present in fillable array of order's model?

Comment: add your model and table struct to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) like

```
 $data = Order::create([
    ...
    'order_date' => Carbon::now()->format('d M Y'),
    ...
]);
```

instead of passing it from form data, and migration to

```
    Schema::table('_table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->string('order_date');
        ...
    });
```

on Model

```
protected $fillable=['user_id', 'order_date', 'order_number', 'payment_method', 'billing_subtotal','billing_tax','billing_total];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your life easier by setting your `order_date` to take on a default value in your migrations:

```php
$table->timestamp('order_date')->useCurrent();
```

Then remove the `order_date` from the `protected $fillable` property in your model.

And also get rid of the form handling for `order_date` in your front-end form.